# Update multiple values based on existing values

Tags: sqlite

I have a table `some_table`:

```
id | some_integer
---|-------------
 1 |      ?
 2 |      ?
 3 |      ?
```

How do I (and can it be done in one query) update `some_table` to:

- Where `id` is `1`, increase `some_integer` by 1
- Where `id` is `2`, decrease `some_integer` by 2
- Where `id` is `3`, increase `some_integer` by 3

To make `some_table` like:

```
id | some_integer
---|-------------
 1 |    ? + 1
 2 |    ? - 2
 3 |    ? + 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE some_table
SET some_integer = some_integer + (CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN -2 WHEN 3 THEN 3 END)
WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET some_integer = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN some_integer + 1
                        WHEN id = 2 THEN some_integer + 2
                        WHEN id = 3 THEN some_integer + 3 END
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```